# Google Translate API for Sanskrit

Tags: google-translation-api

I recently found that Google is now translating English to Sanskrit. Like here: https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=sa&text=friend&op=translate

But I couldn't find the language code in Translate API of GCP. Does somebody know of this?

Answer (score 1):

Translate API and Google Translate are two different products. Sanskrit is not yet released on [Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages).

As a workaround, you may use this [API](https://pypi.org/project/translators/) that uses Google Translate as its back-end.

Sample script:

```
import translators as ts

text='hi'

print(ts.google(query_text=text,to_language='sa'))
```

Output:
[image]

Disclaimer:
The suggested workaround API is subject to limitation as per this [support thread](https://support.google.com/translate/thread/15027713/when-i-am-calling-google-translate-api-multiple-times-in-my-program-it-is-showing-error-why-is-it-so?hl=en&msgid=15147904).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.googleapis.co.in'])
translated = translator.translate("",src='auto', dest='en')

print(translated.text)
```

service_urls allows to use the specific region-google translate. We need to keep src(source) language to auto because if we put "sa"(which is for Sanskirt), It will give an error. Therefore, it is better for it to choose the language itself as "sa".